# IIS Debug: Unable to open script document

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp-classic

Unexpectedly stopped working for me debugging classic ASP in Visual Studio 2015.
I have enabled Server-Side Debugging and on error and trying to lunch VS (and break app) I got error that I need to find file to view source. When I trying to browse for it I got another error with "Unable to open script document".
Also when I set breakpoints in code and app reach this places I got this same message: "Unable to open script document".

I tried to:

- uninstall/install VS
- reset all VS settings
- remove/add IIS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After day of searching solutions I found cause of the problem..
Yesterday I added prefered editor to .asp files in `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `File Extension`. After removing `.asp` extension from list Debugging start working.

Comment: Exactly my issue, wish there was a way to popularize this answer.

Comment: We should also +1 the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but off of a fresh upgrade to Visual Studio 2017. It was my exception settings catching 3rd party java script libraries being loaded in. I fixed this by turning off **JavaScript Runtime Exceptions** and **WebKitJavaScript Exceptions**.